# Extremely slow boot - ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, boot, 64-bit, bootchart

Since installation of Ubuntu Precise I have problem with boot time: nearly 45-60 minutes. I have no idea what's wrong. My system is up to date. I have also boot chart installed but don't know to inter prate the logs. One example is [here](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/38941).

There also other logs from boot chart but I don't understand them.
Regards and thank you for help

Comment: I'm not an expert on boot optimizations but this boot chart seems to be pretty normal looking for your computer's age (I'm guessing it's slightly dated since it's an Athlon dual-core). Also, there's a large period (between ~42-52 seconds) where the system doesn't look to be doing anything. Is that at the login screen? If yes... this really looks like a typical boot.

Comment: Also, it indicates that you're using 11.10, not 12.04...

Comment: Okay, people who keep putting it back to MINUTES instead of SECONDS: Look at the bootchart.

Comment: Hello and thank you all for the answers. The time of booting was changed by me becouse thats fit the true. Not 45seconds but 45minutes takes in best speed the booting time. If the bootchart log is okay thats mean simply that the problem is elswhere. The quastiuon is, where? Aha, I'am runing 12.04 64bit and not 11.10. The booting problem was from the beginning the issue. Before that I was using lucid linx which was booting perfectly.  is there any possibility to find out whats wrong? Could that be some wrong Bios configuration?

Comment: If you could attach a bootchart that deals with your current system instead of an older one, please do attach it. What happens during boot? Is there a black screen for much of it? There might be something that needs user attention and it's not displaying it.

Comment: Hello, sorry that i didnt response so long, pls check this bootchartlog from today: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/39067

Comment: The situation is getting even worser because now i was waiting 3 hours for the boot sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really have to say that it's very likely that your filesystem has been damaged or the upgrade really hosed key system files. I would highly recommend backing up your files and reinstalling as when a system is in such a state it's usually too much hassle to pinpoint the problem.

To back up your files, you can download Ubuntu and use a LiveCD to mount your Ubuntu partition in the file manager. Navigate to /home// and your files will be there for the taking. Back them up to a thumb drive, wipe the computer and reinstall, then move the files back.

Another task that might be beneficial is to make sure that your hard drive is not failing. You can use Ubuntu's Disk Utility: Select your hard drive, then select "SMART data". Perform a short test and see if it tells you that the drive is about to fail (if it has a few bad sectors it's not worth fretting about as it's not uncommon).

Comment: Also, if you want to be very thorough (though it's not necessary to do if you don't want), before you start up the Ubuntu installer you can launch "gparted" through the dash. Select your hard drive after it boots, then select "Device>Create Partition table". Allow it to create a new MBR partition table (the default choice). Then install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Did you find something wrong in the bootchart? I will follow your suggestions. Maybe i will need some more help to bring that in the right way. Bad news..really...Thank you.

Comment: But what I dont understand is, that the boot sequence dosnt hang on Bios or system load sequence but BEFORE. Cold booting get so slow. When I do restart OS, the boot is absolutly normal. Thats mean also filesystem behave normal.I have also made disgnostics of my filesystem and mbr ...there are no errors. There are only physical problems with the soundcard which seams to be broken. I would say that the is the problem of the motherboard or powernet. But anyway...to backup the fules is always a good idea. Thank you

Comment: user43484, you may be right. You may very well have a corrupted BIOS. Did you flash it recently? If you're having other hardware problems it looks like it certainly may be a motherboard issue. You could also look for a BIOS update from your vendor.

Comment: No I didnt flash...but some changes was made to Bios, but not by myself, so i dont really now what. I will bring the computer to the service today..Abslolutly impossible time for having trouble with the hardware right now :-(..Thank you so much for your help anyway!

Comment: OK, YOU CAN CLOSE THIS THREAD. The problem was a burned motherboard. Ive got a new one..all is okay now. Nice weekend to you